# stored procedure for selecting all rows from table in Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

**Please Note:** There are several post regarding this, but I am not getting those due to some key words and why used?
How to create a simple stored procedure in `Oracle` which select all rows from table. I exactly want to create same as below script written in `SQL`. Also How to execute the procedure in Oracle and place in `ASP.NET` `OracleCommand` object.

How to re-write this SQL Stored Procedure in Oracle

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetData
AS
Begin
SELECT * from My_Table;
End
```

Execute is sql

```
execute spGetData
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle 12c has a new feature [Implicit Statement Results](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1) that only requires a few changes to the procedure:

```
SQL> create table My_Table as select 1 a from dual;

Table created.

SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE spGetData
  2  AS
  3     c1 sys_refcursor;
  4  Begin
  5     open c1 for
  6     SELECT * from My_Table;
  7
  8     dbms_sql.return_result(c1);
  9  End;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> execute spGetData

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1

         A
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't have much reputation so instead of comment adding answer.

To Write Store Procedure in Oracle with select all rows you need to include refcursor,as cursor it will work as pointer and point to the oracle result sets one by one and give result.

Store Procedure For Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spGetData(cursorParam OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
 IS
  BEGIN
   OPEN cursorParam FOR
    SELECT * from My_Table;
END ;
```

And to execute it oracle you need

```
   var c refcursor;
    execute spGetData(:c)
   print c;
```

Don't have much knowledge about ASP.NET but may be yo need to add cursor parameter

```
  OracleCommand.Parameters.Add("cursorParam ", OracleType.Cursor).Direction =
ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, this **is** the answer & not a comment, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: while executing a window opens which ask for a value, looks to be parameter. if I provide any value or not, it gives an error for invalid

Comment: cursorParam is OUT type of parameter it is not IN parameter , it should not ask for input, may be you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> > you must want to declare some variable according to your appropriate columns, declare only interested columns you want

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetData
AS
v_emp_id number(20);
v_ename varchar2(20);
Begin
SELECT emp_id,ename into v_emp_id,v_ename from My_Table;
End;
```

> > I think that your error must be expecting into statement ?
> >     so try this one

or

```
DECLARE
TYPE EMP_USER_TYPE IS RECORD (
 EMP_ID        VARCHAR2(10),
emp_name        VARCHAR2(10)
);
TYPE emp_user_tab IS TABLE OF emp_user_type;
emp_user_rec emp_user_tab;
BEGIN
SELECT emp_id,emp_name
BULK COLLECT INTO emp_user_rec
FROM test_employee;
FOR i IN emp_user_rec.FIRST .. emp_user_rec.LAST LOOP
dbms_output.put_line( emp_user_rec(i).emp_id || ', ' || 
emp_user_rec(i).emp_name );
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I have lots of columns, why should I declare one by one, I need to show all.