# pl/sql stored procedure to select from a table where date is equal to stored procedure parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to PL/SQL and oracle, I am using SQL developer 19 against an Oracle 12C database.
All I am trying to do, as I am used to do in T-SQL, is to select some data from a table where a date field value is between two stored procedure ate parameters; below the stored procedure I am using that give to me an error saying that I have to "SELECT INTO" ??

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_DMR_HALO_VALUES ( START_DATE IN DATE , END_DATE IN DATE ) 
AS 

BEGIN    
SELECT 
HALO_RECORD_ID ,
ASSET_ID ,
ASSET_NAME ,
NUMERIC_VALUE ,
IS_ENABLED ,
ADDED_BY ,
VALUE_DATE ,
NOTES ,
DATE_ADDED  

FROM halo_inputs

WHERE trunc(value_date) BETWEEN START_DATE and END_DATE;

END GET_DMR_HALO_VALUES;
```

then I also have another problem... assuming that the above works I am trying to view the returned table data by calling the stored procedure in SQL developer as follow

```
  DEFINE START_DATE date := TO_DATE('2019-02-12','YYYY-DD-MM');
  DEFINE END_DATE date := TO_DATE('2019-02-12','YYYY-DD-MM');

   exec GET_DMR_HALO_VALUES(:START_DATE, :END_DATE );
```

Am I right by calling the SP like above?

**UPDATE**

after looking at this [stack-over article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535034/stored-procedure-for-selecting-all-rows-from-table-in-oracle)
I changed the stored procedure as follow

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_DMR_HALO_VALUES ( START_DATE IN DATE , END_DATE IN DATE ) 
AS 
c1 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
open c1 for
SELECT 
HALO_RECORD_ID ,
ASSET_ID ,
ASSET_NAME ,
NUMERIC_VALUE ,
IS_ENABLED ,
ADDED_BY ,
VALUE_DATE ,
NOTES ,
DATE_ADDED  

FROM halo_inputs

WHERE trunc(value_date) BETWEEN START_DATE and END_DATE;

dbms_sql.return_result(c1);

END;
```

but are cursors the only way in Oracle to get table data ?

**UPDATE 2**
I also changed the exec query as follow

```
DECLARE 
START_DATE date := TO_DATE('12-02-20','DD-MM-YY');
END_DATE date := TO_DATE('12-02-20','DD-MM-YY');

BEGIN
    GET_DMR_HALO_VALUES(START_DATE,END_DATE );
END;
```

and it works but how I get SQL developer to display data in a grid view rather than in plain text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option to make this query return data in data grid is to ... well, run it outside of the stored procedure. Procedures are *nice*, but not *that nice* for doing what you want.

When returning something, a function might be a better choice. For example:

Create it first:

```
SQL> create or replace FUNCTION f_test (par_deptno in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for
  7      select empno, ename, job, sal
  8      from emp
  9      where deptno = par_deptno;
 10    return l_rc;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Then call it:

```
SQL> select f_test(10) from dual;

F_TEST(10)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300


SQL>
```

In SQL Developer, you'd run the last statement (`select f_test(10) from dual;`) **as a script** (F9 keyboard shortcut) and it'll then display the result *nicely* (as my example shows above, although it is SQL Plus command line tool output). Though, it still won't be in a data grid.

Comment: Thanks, the only difference is that in sql developer I call the function like this

DECLARE
  ST_DATE DATE;
  EN_DATE DATE;
  v_Return SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  ST_DATE := to_date('2020-02-12','yyyy-MM-dd');
  EN_DATE := to_date('2020-02-12','yyyy-MM-dd');

  v_Return := FUNC_GET_DMR_HALO_VALUES(START_DATE => ST_DATE,END_DATE => EN_DATE );  
  
END;

Comment: You're welcome. There are several ways of how to do that. Your code, somewhat simplified, might be `select func_get_dmr_halo_values(date '2020-02-12', date '2020-02-12') from dual`. That's just for info; I'm glad you made it.

Comment: I keep seeing this "dual" , but I am not aware of waht this is